# My code in vba is only producing 0 as result despite numerous value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code in excel vba but it is only producing result as 0.

```
Function NDAB(value, average) As Integer
    Dim Val As Integer
    Val = average - value
    If Val > 0 Then
        NDAB = Val / average
    Else
        NDAB = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Seems `Val` is always 0.,. Maybe `average` and `value` have the same value

Comment: Will the division always return an integer?

Comment: Have you checked your input? Is it numeric? Are there cases where `average  > Value` at all?

Comment: What value have you processed ?

Comment: MiguelH points to the the problem: You are doing a division and return an integer. As your division is probanbly a value between 0 and 1 and the result is converted to an int, you see 0 as result

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you number and average can hold, you didn't define them as integers or doubles or longs

also, if you value is larger than the average, you val will be negative.

if you rewrite your code as a sub and run through it using F8 you can see step by step what happens.

```
Sub test()
Dim value As Integer
Dim average As Integer
Dim NDAB As Integer

value = 2
average = 5

    Dim Val As Integer
    Val = average - value
    If Val > 0 Then
        NDAB = Val / average
    Else
        NDAB = 0
    End If

    MsgBox NDAB 
End Sub
```

result in 1
so to me the code is fine, the input is just resulting in 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have try the below and looks to work perfectly:

```
Option Explicit

Function NDAB(ByVal value As Double, ByVal average As Double)

    Dim Val As Double

    Val = average - value

    If Val > 0 Then
        NDAB = Val / average
    Else
        NDAB = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Call Function from sub test:

```
Sub test()

    Call Module1.NDAB(2.5, 10.5)

End Sub
```